# Use nan to receive and return Float32Array in an addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm trying to use [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan) in order to calculate something on an array of floats in an add-on and then return it as a `Float32Array`.

But while the args have `IsNumber()` and `NumberValue()`functions it only has a `IsFloat32Array()` function and no `Float32Array()`.

I've tried to look at those: [1](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples),[2](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) tutorials but found no suitable examples.

```
NAN_METHOD(Calc) {
  NanScope();

  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    NanThrowTypeError("Wrong number of arguments");
    NanReturnUndefined();
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsFloat32Array()) {
    NanThrowTypeError("Wrong arguments");
    NanReturnUndefined();
  }
  /* a vector of floats ? */  args[0]-> ???;
  double arg1 = args[1]->NumberValue();
  // some calculation on the vector

  NanReturnValue(/* Return as a Float32Array array */);
}
```

Comment: It seems that one has to rely on v8 specific constructs for now, since we don't have enough typed array helpers in nan yet: https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/521

Answer (score 2):

Accepting a TypedArray is best done with `Nan::TypedArrayContents`

```
Local<TypedArray> ta = args[0].As<TypedArray>();
Nan::TypedArrayContents<float> vfloat(ta);
float firstElement = (*vfloat)[0];
```

There is no NAN helper for constructing a typed array yet, but I use this helper in my own code:

```
template <typename T> struct V8TypedArrayTraits; // no generic case
template<> struct V8TypedArrayTraits<Float32Array> { typedef float value_type; };
template<> struct V8TypedArrayTraits<Float64Array> { typedef double value_type; };
// etc. v8 doesn't export anything to make this nice.

template <typename T>
Local<T> createTypedArray(size_t size) {
  size_t byteLength = size * sizeof(typename V8TypedArrayTraits<T>::value_type);
  Local<ArrayBuffer> buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), byteLength);
  Local<T> result = T::New(buffer, 0, size);
  return result;
};
```